# Magento2 admin Menus not working

Tags: magento2, admin, menu

I have installed Magento2 successfully but there is having some issue on the backend side when i login to the admin side menus not working at all, (frontend is working fine). I have tried all the cache, content deploy, permissions commannd but nothing is working at all.

[image]

Comment: Check if any `JS` error by pressing **F12** in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is a backend setting that appears to be often the origin of this issue you're having; you may check the core_config_data table

```
 select * from core_config_data where path like '%dev/static/sign%';
```

the value for this path should be 0 (see screenshot)

[image]

then flush cache and browser cache, and you may see your javascript working again

**EDIT:** if the record is not there in the first place, then, just add it:

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');
```

Comment: I din't find any record like that in my 'core_config_data' Table

Comment: Any Suggestions ?

Comment: yes, I made an update indeed

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
Delete all folders under pub/static
Delete var/cache
Delete var/composer_home
Delete var/generation
Delete var/page_cache
Delete var/view_preprocessed
```

Run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

If your site is multi-language, run the below code.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f nl_BE
```

Other way is got to database and go to **`core_config_data`** table. And Search for path **`dev/static/sign`** and set value to **`0`**.

**`Clean cache :`**

```
rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ var/di/ pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/
```

If you do not find it in the table, run the below query in the database.

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');
```

Then follow steps run below command

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f (If multi-language run command like this php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f nl_BE)
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

If any query let me know.

**`THANKS.`**